# How to compare two skeletons by using kinect sensor?

Tags: c#, kinect

I need to know about how to compare record skeleton with live skeleton in C#. If there are any reference please let me know.

[example image for what I done up to now](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_wEmseJ5VrDS21RVC1kVC1nZkE/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to perform?

Comment: A person who followed recorded skeleton. As a example a patient follow exercise.

Comment: This is full-body gesture recognition - that is a Hard problem, and [solutions will generally be much longer and more complicated](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=kinect+gesture+recognition&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4ueaSutXNAhXB6IMKHbbgAmcQgQMIGjAA) than what fits comfortably in a StackExchange answer. To get a concise, useful answer, it would help to narrow the problem domain. Try including a diagram or video of one motion you're trying to recognize, and what you've tried so far / what issues you're trying to fix.

Comment: In my project up to now I can get recognition of person and get angle measurements of body. This work perfectly. Now I need to compare this skeleton with another.